# Merging on NOT NULL values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, notnull

I have an empty table consisting of NULL (42 col.) and NOT NULL columns (14 columns). In total 56 columns.
That is `Dest` table I'd like to merge onto.
I have to update only 4 columns. All the remaining columns I'd like to remain untouched.
How would I achieve that?

My code:

```sql
merge into [tempdb].[dbo].[#Correspondence] Dest
using [tempdb].[dbo].[#toBeTransferred] Src
on (Dest.[CaseId] = Src.[CaseId])
when matched and (Dest.[CaseId] != Src.[CaseId])
    then
    update
    set Dest.[CaseId] = Src.[CaseId]
when not matched then
    insert ([CaseId],
            [Description],
            [Date],
            [Link],
            [RecipientAddressID],
            [Faxed],
            [CertifiedMail],
            [CCRecipientAddressID],
            [MergeTemplates],
            [BCCRecipientAddressID],
            [CorrespondenceFromAddressID],
            [RegularMail],
            [Sent],
            [ExpertsLinked],
            [EMailed],
            [HandDelivered],
            [UseDocusign],
            [Privileged]
            )
    values (Src.[CaseId], Src.[Description], Src.[Date], Src.[Link], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It works, but I had to use 0 as a workaround to pass the NOT NULL error on the update. 
What would be a better way?

Comment: Sounds like you want to set a default constraint on the NOT NULL columns?

Comment: `on (Dest.[CaseId] = Src.[CaseId]) when matched and (Dest.[CaseId] != Src.[CaseId])` doesn't make the slightest bit of sense, it's never going to hit that condition obviously. Also `#` temp tables don't need database or schema references

Comment: This is a very simple pattern and there are much better and more established ways to do this than `MERGE` IMHO - please see these links https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: In an insert there is no 'untouched'. No data actually exists in those columns so there's nothing existing to be "untouched". I suggest you make sure you understand the difference between `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, and likely lose the `MERGE` altogether.

Comment: Consider using the keyword `default` instead of `0`. Columns with the `not null` property should already have a default constraint specified, nullable columns will just receive `null`.